# How to resolve ID (Django ORM) that generates with SQL script on DB

Tags: python, sql-server, django, django-models, pymssql

Django ORM doesn't resolve id that generates in DB with special SQL trigger  while record inserting.
When I'm saving model without ID it saves correctly and have ID in DB? but `m.id` returns me `None`.

```
class SomeModel(Model):
   id = IntegerField(primary_key=True)
   name = CharField(null=False, max=50)

m = SomeModel(name='asd')
m.save()
m.id # - None
```

How I can resolve autogenerated ID after saving? Or how I can rewrite `save()` method? Or maybe change field type?

I need to use my own trigger instead of `IDENTITY`!

Comment: Why did you define the `id` field as an IntegerField? In fact why did you define it at all, rather than letting Django do so automatically?

Comment: @DanielRoseman because I need to know id name to use it in migration (that adds trigger, that generates ID)

Comment: But Django doesn't know about your trigger, so it doesn't know that the field will be populated by the db.

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes I know, and how I can tell django about this?

Answer (score 0):

Please read Django documentation. By default you don't need say to Django what is primary key. But if you wanna.

```
class SomeModel(Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_index=True)
   name = CharField(null=False, max=50)
```

Comment: AutoField adds IDENTITY(1, 1), but I need to use my trigger instead of it.